# vue router $router.replace not working properly when client side routing in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I have search page where I am updating the query string with the updated filter values using `$router.replace({params: filters});`. But when I navigate to the filter page from another page using client side navigation `$router.replace()` is being aborted. Here is my code:

**component**

```
<filter-section
      @filterSearch="filter"
      @toggleView="handleToggleView"
      :currentlySelected="view_type"
      @mapViewMounted="loadMarkers" />
```

**methods**

```
           async filter(filters) {
                this.listLoading = true;

                this.APPLY_SEARCH_FILTER(filters);

                // changes the query parameters in the url to be in sync with the current filters
                this.$router.replace({query: filters}, () => {
                    // when the page is refreshed and the page is server rendered
                    // then this is working fine
                    console.log('Route replace complete');
                }, () => {
                    // when navigated to this page using client side 
                    // routing the route replace is being aborted
                    console.log('Route replace abort');
                });

                let { data } = await this.$api.Search.groups(filters);

                let groups = data.data.groups;
                let meta = data.data.meta;

                this.STORE_SEARCH_RESULTS({
                    groups: groups,
                    meta: meta
                });

                this.listLoading = false;

                this.loadMarkers();
            },
```

I am routing to this page from another page like this `this.$router.push('/search?${searchString}');`
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: it's probably some other logic is blocking the redirection. for example, logic in `beforeRouteEnter` could abort a certain route redirection

Comment: @JacobGoh I do not have any `beforeRouteEnter` hook in router.